# Children's short story where prehistoric childen have to cross a predator's territory

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

This was a short story in a children's magazine in the English language in the USA about 1960.  Possibly in *Jack and Jill*.

I am not certain whether this was before or after we moved in November 1961.

As I remember, the protagonist were prehistoric hunter-gatherer children.  And near their home there was a region, a flat grassy meadow, or maybe a swamp filled with water plants, inhabited by some dangerous predator.  And naturally a situation came when the kids had to cross the hunting ground of that "man eating monster".  That's all I remember about the plot.

And I think that I remember wondering what sort of known animal the predator could be while reading the story.  I certainly do not remember anything about it. Maybe it was a giant snake, or a crocodile, or a dinosaur if the story wasn't scientifically accurate.

And I am not certain whether the story was in a prehistoric era.  Possibly the kids part of a group of hunter-gatherers in some remote region of the world in the 1960s or in an earlier historic eras.